# loop across multiple urls in r with rvest

Tags: html, r, url, web-scraping, rvest

I have a series of 9 urls that I would like to scrape data from:

```
http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/draft_finder.cgi?request=1&year_min=2001&year_max=2014&round_min=&round_max=&pick_overall_min=&pick_overall_max=&franch_id=&college_id=0&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=year_id&order_by_asc=&offset=0
```

The offset= at the end of the link goes from 0 up to 900 (by 100) when pages change through the last page.  I would like to loop through each page and scrape each table, then use rbind to stack each df on top of one another in sequence.  I have been using rvest and would like to use lapply since I am better with that than for loops.

The question is similar to this ([Harvest (rvest) multiple HTML pages from a list of urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906601)) but different because I would prefer not to have to copy all the links to one vector before running the program.  I would like a general solution to how to loop over multiple pages and harvest the data, creating a data frame each time.

The following works for the first page:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

site <- 'http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/draft_finder.cgi?request=1&year_min=2001&year_max=2014&round_min=&round_max=&pick_overall_min=&pick_overall_max=&franch_id=&college_id=0&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=year_id&order_by_asc=&offset=0' 

webpage <- read_html(site)
draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
draft <- html_table(draft_table)[[1]]
```

But I would like to repeat this over all pages without having to paste the urls into a vector.  I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
jump <- seq(0, 900, by = 100)
site <- paste('http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/draft_finder.cgi?request=1&year_min=2001&year_max=2014&round_min=&round_max=&pick_overall_min=&pick_overall_max=&franch_id=&college_id=0&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=year_id&order_by_asc=&offset=', jump,'.htm', sep="")

webpage <- read_html(site)
draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
draft <- html_table(draft_table)[[1]]
```

So there should be a data frame for each page and I imagine it would be easier to put them in a list and then use rbind to stack them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you manage to harvest even the first page?

Comment: @HubertL yes just edited the question above.  The first chunk of code produces one data frame

Comment: Here is another potential solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129125/how-to-scrape-all-pages-1-2-3-n-from-a-website-using-r-vest/39131227#39131227

Comment: In the second version, `site` is a vector of URLs, so this is a dupe.

Comment: I would try `download.file` with mode="a" and then read all the data from a single disk file.

Comment: @alistaire I don't think this is a dupe because the other question uses a pre-constructed vector of urls, while this one asks how to perform a similar task without already having all the urls in one place.

Comment: You've already shown how to construct the vector of URLs above; that's not the part that's not working. The part you need is to `lapply`/`purrr::map` across the vector `site`, of which the dupe shows an example, and of [which](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33771265/4497050) [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28823270/4497050) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30586480/4497050) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140133/scraping-tables-on-multiple-web-pages-with-rvest-in-r) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36683510/4497050) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38114066/4497050).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are attempting to vectorize a method that cannot take multiple items in one call. Specifically, `read_html()` requires one page per call since it needs to read in web data one at a time and expects a scalar value. Consider looping through the `site` list with `lapply` then bind all dfs together:

```
jump <- seq(0, 800, by = 100)
site <- paste('http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/draft_finder.cgi?',
              'request=1&year_min=2001&year_max=2014&round_min=&round_max=',
              '&pick_overall_min=&pick_overall_max=&franch_id=&college_id=0',
              '&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y',
              '&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=',
              '&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=year_id',
              '&order_by_asc=&offset=', jump, sep="")

dfList <- lapply(site, function(i) {
    webpage <- read_html(i)
    draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
    draft <- html_table(draft_table)[[1]]
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)             # ASSUMING ALL DFs MAINTAIN SAME COLS
```

Comment: this is really intuitive but I keep getting an error "subscript is out of bounds" when I run it.

Comment: At what line do you receive error? Does `dfList` populate?

Comment: it appears the error comes from the final line of dfList.  dfList does not populate

Comment: Just checked. Turns out `900` has no table search results. Try leaving that number out. Highest rank is `831`.

Comment: Does error persist with leaving out last url with `900`?

Comment: yes, it still persists.  Even dropping the last url with 900 returns the following error message:     "Error in html_table(draft_table)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Just found the issue. No need for `.htm` at the end and still leave out 900.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `curl` to run all of the requests at once. I  Be nice to the sites that may have small servers and don't blow them up.  With this code you can use the `lapply` at the end to clean up the table so you can stack it with `do.call(rbind, AllOut)` but I will leave that to you.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

OffSet <- seq(0, 900, by = 100)

Sites <- paste0('http://www.basketball-reference.com/play-index/draft_finder.cgi?request=1&year_min=2001&year_max=2014&round_min=&round_max=&pick_overall_min=&pick_overall_max=&franch_id=&college_id=0&is_active=&is_hof=&pos_is_g=Y&pos_is_gf=Y&pos_is_f=Y&pos_is_fg=Y&pos_is_fc=Y&pos_is_c=Y&pos_is_cf=Y&c1stat=&c1comp=&c1val=&c2stat=&c2comp=&c2val=&c3stat=&c3comp=&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=&c4val=&order_by=year_id&order_by_asc=&offset=', OffSet)


library(curl)

out <<- list()
# This is function, function which will be run if data vendor call is successful
complete = function(res){
  # cat("Request done! Status:", res$status, "\n")
  out <<- c(out, list(res))
}

for(i in 1:length(Sites)){
  curl_fetch_multi(
    Sites[i]
    , done = complete
    , fail = print
    , handle = new_handle(customrequest = "GET")
    )
}

multi_run()

AllOut <- lapply(out, function(x){

  webpage <- read_html(x$content)
  draft_table <- html_nodes(webpage, 'table')
  Tab <- html_table(draft_table)
  if(length(Tab) == 0){
    NULL
  } else {
    Tab
  }

})
```