# Extracting data from more than one page of TripAdvisor results

Tags: r, web-scraping, tripadvisor

I'm trying to scrape data from TripAdvisor search results that span several pages using rvest.

Here's my code:

```
library(rvest)

starturl <- 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Search?q=swim+with&uiOrigin=trip_search_Attractions&searchSessionId=CA54193AF19658CB1D983934FB5C86F41511875967385ssid#&ssrc=A&o=0'

swimwith <- read_html(starturl)

swdf <- swimwith %>%
html_nodes('.title span') %>%
html_text()
```

It works fine for the first page of results, but I can't figure out how to get results from the subsequent pages. I noticed that the end of the url denotes the start position of the results, so I changed it from '0' to '30' as follows:

```
url <- sub('A&o=0', paste0('A&o=', '30'), starturl)

webpage <- html_session(url)
swimwith <- read_html(webpage)

swdf2 <- swimwith %>%
html_nodes('.title span') %>%
html_text()
```

However, the results for `swdf2` are the same as `swdf` even though the url loads the second page of results in a web browser.

Any idea how I can get the results from these subsequent pages?

Comment: I think you won't get past using Selenium (and even then I am not sure it will work).

Comment: What happens if you start a fresh session of R, and try with the URL: `starturl <- 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Search?q=swim+with&uiOrigin=trip_search_Attractions&searchSessionId=CA54193AF19658CB1D983934FB5C86F41511875967385ssid#&ssrc=A&o=30'`, do you get the second page?

Comment: I should also add that rvest has functions to navigate a website follow_link() and jump_to() but they don’t work here because the links are JavaScript buttons.

Comment: @Mako212 I just tried starting a new session with the second page link but it still gets results from the first page.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer are you saying I need to use Selenium?

Comment: Yes! The Javascript nature of the page's navigation is the problem. I recently coded some scrapers using Selenium as well. I had the feeling that it is still a little more stable to use Python + Selenium than RSelenium.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer thanks. I'm currently looking into RSelenium but can't get the selenium server running yet...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
jump <- seq(0, 300, by = 30)
site <- paste('https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Search?q=swim+with&uiOrigin=trip_search_Attractions&searchSessionId=CA54193AF19658CB1D983934FB5C86F41511875967385ssid#&ssrc=A&o=', jump, sep="")

dfList <- lapply
(site, function(i) 
{

  swimwith <- read_html(i)

  swdf <- swimwith %>%
  html_nodes('.title span') %>%
  html_text()


}
)

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

It doesn't work in my office because the firewall is blocking it, but I think that should work for you.

Also, take a look at the links below.

https://rpubs.com/ryanthomas/webscraping-with-rvest

[loop across multiple urls in r with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666406/loop-across-multiple-urls-in-r-with-rvest)

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1) Here is an approach based on the R package RSelenium :

```
library(RSelenium)

# Note : You have to install chromedriver 
rd <- rsDriver(chromever = "96.0.4664.45", browser = "chrome", port = 4450L) 
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Search?q=swim+with&uiOrigin=trip_search_Attractions&searchSessionId=CA54193AF19658CB1D983934FB5C86F41511875967385ssid#&ssrc=A&o=0")

remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

list_Text <- list()

for(i in 1 : 30)
{
  print(i)
  web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", paste0("//*[@id='BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[", i, "]"))
  list_Text[[i]] <- web_Obj$getElementText()  
}
```

Note : You have to install chromedriver.

Approach 2) If you are looking to extract the titles only, you can print the webpage to PDF and extract the text from the PDF afterwards. Here is an example :

```
library(pagedown)
library(pdftools)
chrome_print("https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Search?q=swim+with&uiOrigin=trip_search_Attractions&searchSessionId=CA54193AF19658CB1D983934FB5C86F41511875967385ssid#&ssrc=A&o=0",
             "C:\\...\\trip_advisor.pdf")

text <- pdf_text("C:\\...\\trip_advisor.pdf")
text  <- strsplit(text, split = "\r\n")

# The titles are in the variable text ...
```